# Toggle change class for button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, colors, toggle

I have buttons. Buttons have the function which shows/hide some text. I'd like to set button different color when it's clicked and when i click again. Color is changed back.

I think i go wrong. In this case i don't see how i could change it back. Ofc i can use `.removeClass(".clicked")` but i dont know how to set this function for every even click.

```
$(".toggle").click(function () {
  $(".toggle").addClass("clicked");
});
```

Another option is use something like this `'green' ? 'red' : 'green';` but tbh. I've started with JS like 2 weeks ago and i no have noidea..

I'm not sure if it's important information. But the buttons are generated from this code via  `ForEach loop`

```
function toggle(i) {
  const divs = document.querySelectorAll(
    `#text_${i},
    #result_${i},
    #image_${i}`
  );

  for (let div of divs) {
    if (div.style.display !== "none") {
      div.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      div.style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}

const container = document.querySelector("#examples-container");

examples.forEach((ex, i) => {
  // Make the div for the <div class="card">
  const card = document.createElement("div");
  // Add the "card" class to the div
  card.classList.add("card");

  // Create the div for the <div class="example">${ex.question}</div>
  const example = document.createElement("div");
  // Add the "example" class
  example.classList.add("example");
  // Set the HTML inside of it to ex.question
  example.innerHTML = ex.question;
  // Add it to the card element
  card.appendChild(example);

  // Create the button for the <button class="Toggle">Toggle</button>
  const button = document.createElement("button");
  // Add the "toggle" class to the button
  button.classList.add("toggle");
  // Set the text inside of it to say "Toggle"
  button.innerHTML = "výsledek";
  // Add the onclick event listener
  button.addEventListener("click", () => toggle(i));
  // Add the toggle button to the card
  card.appendChild(button);

  //For answer
  // Create the div for the <div id="result_${i}" class="result">${ex.answer}</div>
  const result = document.createElement("div");
  // Add the id for the element
  result.id = "result_" + i;
  // Hide the result element (display: none)
  result.style.display = "none";
  // Add the "result" class
  result.classList.add("result");
  // Set it's HTML to the answer
  result.innerHTML = ex.answer;
  // Add the result element to the card
  card.appendChild(result);

  //For Image
  const image = document.createElement("div");
  image.id = "image_" + i;
  image.style.display = "none";
  image.classList.add("image");
  image.innerHTML = ex.image;
  card.appendChild(image);

  //For Text
  const text = document.createElement("div");
  text.id = "text_" + i;
  text.style.display = "none";
  text.classList.add("text");
  text.innerHTML = ex.text;
  card.appendChild(text);

  // Add the card to the container
  container.appendChild(card);
});
```

Comment: Instead of `$(".toggle").addClass("clicked");` ... try with: `$(".toggle").toggleClass("clicked");` ? ... with each click will add the class if not present, or remove it if present.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend simplifying your code by enclosing your three answers (`#result_N`, `#image_N`, `#text_N`) into a div with ID `#answer_N`. That way you can simplify your toggle function as follows:

```
function toggle(i) {
  $(`#answer_${i}`).toggleClass('clicked');
}
```